Move instances on curves using geometry nodes
I have a simple set up where I am generating some curves using geo nodes. I want to move my instances on these curves but I am not able to figure out how to move all of them in one go. For a single curve and instance I can use the sample curve node and select a curve index and use its factor as the position offset of my index, but how do I do it if I have multiple curves and I want to move all the instances simultaneously.
Here is my geo nodes setup. I want to figure out a way to move my instances from A to B (preferably by using the curve factor since I may want to tweak the lengths of individual curves later)


Sample Curve node has a curve index input, that you can pass an instance index to, so that for each instance you're sampling the curve associated (by index) with this instance.

Wow! This worked. Thanks so much.

Hi, @MarkusvonBroady..  this looks like a quick answer, if you can give it a minute.. unless Broly would prefer to close the question out...

Sure, happy to mark as an answer once added.
